# JavaScript "action listener"/button listener not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

This should be a simple fix. I'm experienced in Java, however slowly but surely learning Javascript. I'm building a website that's kinda fun. Anyways, the part I'm working on now is using the parse api. My plan (since there appeared to be no better way) is to use parse to communicate with my clients android tablet from my ruby on rails website app. My problem is the button does not trigger the parse function. Here's the code I wrote so far:***(Note my code it not complete html, since it's a rails app)*** Also, If you wouldn't mind explaining a general syntactical difference between java and javascript that would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.15.min.js"></script>
<h1>New status</h1>


    <input id ="username" /> 
    <input id ="password" />

    <button id="registerBtn" value="Register">Register</button><button id="signInBtn" value="Sign in">Sign in</button>


          <script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("XXX", "XXX");

    $("#registerBtn").click(function() {
        var user = new Parse.User();
        user.set("username", $("#username").val());
        user.set("password", $("#password").val());

        user.signUp(null, {
            success: function(user) {
                alert("Successfully registered!");
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " error.message);

            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Use Firebug addon and check if any javascript error thrown in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo in

```
alert("Error: " + error.code + " " error.message);
```

add `+`

```
alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
```

Seems you are new to web development check [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/20-tools-to-make-the-life-of-a-web-developer-easier/) for some important tools of a web developer

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated on the link.